# Clojure Repl - Is there a way to see what variables have been defined (and are thus available) in a REPL session?

Tags: clojure

If I've been playing around in a clojure REPL (might have been experimenting with (assoc) or (seq) or (reduce) and created some temporary maps for examples), but wanted to print a listing of variables defined in that session, is there a way to do this?  Something like (println def) or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `(dir user)` if you are in the `user` namespace.  Or any other ns you are interested into.  This shows you all the `def`-ed things.  If it's not there (it usually gets `use`ed automatically in the REPL, you can find it in `clojure.repl/dir`).

Answer (score 6):

[`ns-interns`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-interns) can get you pretty close I think.

```
user=> (def x 1)
#'user/x
user=> (def y 2)
#'user/y
user=> (ns-interns *ns*)
{x #'user/x, y #'user/y}
```